# Babel formatting error for negative values in currency

Tags: python, python-babel, format-currency

I try to format floats into currency-strings with babel. The following code:

```
from babel.numbers import format_currency

print(format_currency(value, 'CHF', locale='de_CH'))
print(format_currency(value, 'CHF', '¤¤ #,##0.00', locale='de_CH'))
print(format_currency(value, 'CHF', '#,##0.00', locale='de_CH'))
```

results in the following formatting errors:

CHF-100.50

-CHF 100.50

-CHF 100.50

I would expect the following result:

CHF -100.50

what am I doing wrong? can't figure out the error. Thank you very much for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue a while back. I couldn't find any way to do it with format strings, so I create a small hack-around function:

```
from babel.numbers import format_currency


def format_currency_fix(val, currency, locale=None):
    return format_currency(val, currency, '¤¤ #,##0.00;¤¤ -#,##0.00',
                           locale=locale)


value = -100.50
print(format_currency_fix(value, 'CHF', locale='de_CH'))  # => CHF -100.50
print(format_currency_fix(value, 'USD', locale='es_CO'))  # => USD -100,50
```

(Thanks to [DenverCoder1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11608064/denvercoder1) for shortening the code to a one-liner)

You lose a bit of customizability, but it worked for all my use cases.

Comment: thanks for that input. I thought about doing the same thing, but I was hoping, that this is not a bug in babel (which I assume this is). 
If nobody comes up with the perfect solution, I will have to use your workaround.

Comment: sure will do. but I hope for a better answer ;.-)

Comment: @user2828408 This does seem like a bug, so I've opened an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/python-babel/babel/issues/937).

Comment: You could use a semicolon to separate positive and negative formats like `'¤¤ #,##0.00;¤¤ -#,##0.00'`, so you can do it with only 1 line -- `format_currency(value, 'CHF', '¤¤ #,##0.00;¤¤ -#,##0.00', locale='de_CH')`

Comment: @DenverCoder1 Thanks for the great suggestion! I've edited my question with the update (giving attribution, of course).